# Hibernate session error in Vaadin

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, vaadin

I´m developing a Vaadin webapp using [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.html) with hibernate 4.3.
I followed the instructions of this [link](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.hibernate.html) and implemented EntityManager-per-Request pattern successfully. That means the lazy loading works well with JPAContainer

However, every time I need to use pure JPA, it fails to lazy loads.

Here is an example code:

```
 try {
    entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();

    List<SubEntity> subEntitiesList = myEntity.getCollectionOfEntities(); //Fails to load

    for (SubEntity subEntity : subEntitiesList) {
        subEntity.doSomething();
        entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager().merge(subEntity);
    }
    entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager().flush();
    entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
}

//datasource is JPAContainer<MyEntity>  type
datasource.removeItem(index);
```

I have tried this solutions:

1. Use hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans
   It opened an session automatically, but it gave a serious warning:

   "Unable to close temporary session used to load lazy collection associated to no session"

Also, when I remove the Entity from the JPAContainer, I receive an error: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Can someone give me some hints on how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two approaches.

**Merge the changes of a detached entity to database**

Just merge the entity and operate on the managed value.

```
Entity managed = em.merge(entity);

for (SubEntity sub : managed.getSubEntities()) {
    sub.doSomething();
}
```

**Resolve lazy proxies without touching the DB**

Find the entity by ID and copy properties to the detached entity.

```
Entity managed = em.find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId());
entity.setSubEntities(managed.getSubEntities());
```

For the second option I wrote a generic utility method to initialize detached entities to some depth 
that  maybe you would  find it useful.

```
// initialize lazy collections and collection elements
JpaUtils.initialize(em, entity, 2);
```

See [JpaUtils](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jdal/dao/jpa/JpaUtils.java) for source code.

Comment: Thanks Jose! Great Answer!  One last question: using the second approach, what if I use em.getReference instead of em.find ?

Comment: @guilhermecgs It's fine, specially if you only want to initialize some properties.